# How To Write Python 3 Import Statements When Running as Module and as Installed Program?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

**Problem**

I find the importing process of Python is great in one context but often fails entirely in another. I have situation where I'm creating a program that can be run as a module or installed. It works one way (as a module), does not another (installed). It comes down to how I'm importing. What I don't know is how to fix it.

Note: This program will only ever run on Python 3.

**Example of Problem**

Here is the code repo that shows the problem: https://github.com/jeffnyman/pacumen

If you clone that, you can run the following in the project root:

```
python3 -m pacumen
```

And it works just fine.

Now, however, I want to install it. So from the project root:

```
pip3 install .
```

That works (via my [setup.py](https://github.com/jeffnyman/pacumen/blob/master/setup.py)) but then you should be able to run the program like this:

```
pacumen
```

The program runs but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pacumen", line 7, in <module>
   from pacumen.__main__ import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pacumen/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  from .mechanics import layout
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pacumen.mechanics'
```

That's clearly due to [my import statement](https://github.com/jeffnyman/pacumen/blob/master/pacumen/__main__.py#L5).

But it's not clear what I can do to fix this. I'm finding most Python documentation to be singularly unhelpful in resolving import issues because what it tells me works in one context but not in another. I'm no doubt missing something.

**What I've Tried**

I have tried adding the following line to my `__init__.py`:

```
from .__main__ import *
```

This was from other comments on other questions. That, however, does not work. The same error is generated.

I tried changing my import in `__main__.py` to be this:

```
from pacumen.mechanics import layout
```

That was also a suggestion from another question. That, too, does not work. Same error.

My import can't be categorically wrong because it works while running as a module. So I'm not sure if my setup is being done inaccurately or if I need something else in `__init__.py` or if what I'm trying to do is in fact not something that you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course, I think I found my answer after posting the above. I'm not sure if this is right but it seems to work so I'll document this as an answer in case someone else comes across this question.

What I had to do was add the following to my setup.py:

```
packages=['pacumen', 'pacumen.mechanics'],
```

Previously I only had this:

```
packages=['pacumen'],
```

I will clearly have to do that for every directory that I create.